# Как вставить эти картинки background?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

есть макет, верстаю по нему. сделать его нужно на сетке бутстрап, нарезал задний фон, а как вставить его не понимаю, как лучше его установить туда? создать div и сделать его нужной высоты, вставить туда картинку, а затем добавить туда контейнер и начать выставлять сетку в нём или как?

[image: пример]

Comment: как обычно ...делаете блок с нужной высотой и шириной ..на фон ставите нужную картинку и всё

Comment: @MaximLensky это никак не помешает работе сетки? я плохо ещё разбираюсь в бутстрапе

Comment: @СотниЛичностей Не помешает

Comment: не помешает ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не важно, бутстрап или нет, главное задавать фон всему блоку, к примеру к первому экрану.
В нём уже создавать контейнер и дальше уже сам контент.

Вот пример, но только без бутстрапа.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bg {
  /* Вот эта секция с фоном */
  height: 500px;
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558429886-f2d4fa936469?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80) no-repeat center center
}

.menu {
  padding-top: 2em;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cover {
  margin-top: 4em;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
}

.button {
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: .5em 2em;
  border: 1px solid #ffbb00;
  color: #ffbb00;
  font-size: 1em;
  background: none;
  transition: .3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #ffbb00;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!-- Вот эта секция с фоном -->
<section class="bg">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h1 class="cover">
      Hello, I'm cover text
    </h1>
    <button type="button" class="button">Touch</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: а почему не адаптивно ?

Comment: может еще и сайт сверстать на коленке ?))

Это как пример использование фона в блоке.